# weird error using SQL-Server2005 SPROCs from MS Access 2000: ";1" in name --> not found

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, stored-procedures

I have a weird problem here.

In short to the environment we have:

There is a (newly set up) Win2003 Server with a SQL Server 2005 Express database. I connect to it via a MS Access application.

Since I switched to the new server (restored a backup from the former server on it) all SPROCs (only in Access) have a ;1 after their name, hence cannot be found.

If I try to open a SPROC in Access (dbl click in overview), it asks for the parameter, then says cannot be found.
If I try to open, say, a report based on it, same result. If I change the name of the SPROC the report is based on to the name shown in the overview ( [sprocnam];1 ) it says "cannot be found" (of course, because the names did not change as one can see in Management Studio).

?!?

keep in mind that the Access-application worked fine with the database that I backed up on another server and restored to the newly set up server ...

Your help is greatly appreciated!

**edit:** I found a thread on SAP.com with someone experiencing the same problem, but without a solution: https://forums.sdn.sap.com/message.jspa?messageID=7947957

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue with an **update** of the clients **office**-installation to the latest service pack.

The one employee that notified me of the problem and me got new computers last week, and thus did not have the latest updates.

Answer (score 3):

I can't tell why you have got this issue, but in In SQL Server you have the ability to create Numbered stored procedures. The procedures have the same name but may contain completely different code, look at this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTest] 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @@MICROSOFTVERSION
END

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTest];2
AS
SELECT @@version

GO

EXEC spTest;1
EXEC spTest;2
```

Comment: +1. This 'group number' feature may also be why Crystal Reports adds ";1" to procedure calls automatically.